# Backup network drive W2016 domain account with logon as batch job without password

Tags: windows, unc, cifs

I have a problem to backup a CIFS resource at W2016 server via UNC path. The CIFS are shared with everyone permissions,

I use an external scheduler that runs a batch with a domain user with logon as batch permissions (No interactive login), but the backup fails with an error related to cannot find the share.

I test to map the drive with the external scheduler and Domain user account with logon as batch rights, and all the times request for a password that i don't know (because this password are keeped at external scheduler)

I was done many tests with this results:

1- If i map the network drive with another user, or configure a logon to map the drive, when i run the job/batch with the domain user with logon as batch rights, and run a net use, i cannot see the drive mapped.

2- If i run a net use to map the drive with the domain user using a batch file with the logon as batch permissions, the process request the user password (i don't have the password, this credential are configured internally at external scheduler) and cannot map the drive

3- If i run a backup with the external scheduler/batch file, i have an error related that the path are not exist.

I understand, that when i run net use of the drive in interactive sesion, are using the credentials of that session, but i don't understand why using the domain user with logon as batch don't use this credentials and request a password to connect to map the shared network,

¿The Domain user with logon as batch credentials, can map a network share or backup accesing UNC path directly, without password?

I testing to storage the key at windows to access the UNC path, but the result returns a bad username/password and request for the password producing an error to the process.